# ¿Cómo modificar el contenido HTML en un DIV dinámico con Tampermonkey?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy tratando de crear un script para Tampermonkey que lea un div que cambia en cada página y que agregue un código html dentro de él. He intentado usar `document.getElementById` pero como cambia no sé cómo hacer que lo lea. Lo intenté con div padre que lea y busco el div hijo y que lo meta en un array. También necesito poder lee la id del div, ejemplo "474325031b1111181856dc6fe54bcb4c" y la primera parte del texto del elementó `a class="obvious"`, ejemplo "KB000012345 - UNTEXTO" del cual solo necesito "KB000012345" para que pase esos datos al código html que quiero introducir en el div.

Aquí un ejemplo de lo que quiero modificar:

```
    <div class="custom-form-group   form-group ng-scope" sn-atf-whitelist="true" sn-ng-formatter="" sn-ng-compiled="true"><table style="width: 100%;" class="" role="presentation">
    <tbody><tr><td class="label label_spacing">
        <span style="margin-right:3px; margin-left:1px;">&nbsp;</span>Attached knowledge:</td><td>
            <div id="474325031b1111181856dc6fe54bcb4c"> //ID dinamica cambia siempre
                <img src="images/nav_bult.gifx" alt="Knowledge Base Article"><a class="obvious" href="kb_view.do?sys_kb_id=6ff24492db76574839a16d15ca9619ba">KB000012345 - UNTEXTO</a></div>
                  </td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Para que quede de esta manera:

```
<div class="custom-form-group   form-group ng-scope" sn-atf-whitelist="true" sn-ng-formatter="" sn-ng-compiled="true"><table style="width: 100%;" class="" role="presentation">
        <tbody><tr><td class="label label_spacing">
            <span style="margin-right:3px; margin-left:1px;">&nbsp;</span>Attached knowledge:</td><td>
            <div id="474325031b1111181856dc6fe54bcb4c">
                <img src="delete_button.gif" width="18" height="18" onclick="delete_this('474325031b1111181856dc6fe54bcb4c', 'KB000012345')">
                    <img src="images/nav_bult.gifx" alt="Knowledge Base Article"><a class="obvious" href="kb_view.do?sys_kb_id=6ff24492db76574839a16d15ca9619ba">KB000012345 - UNTEXTO</a></div>
                        </td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Solo es agregar este código dentro del div:

```
<img src="delete_button.gif" width="18" height="18" onclick="delete_this('474325031b1111181856dc6fe54bcb4c', 'KB000012345')">
```